# circular progress bar flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  });
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('event_profile/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
  var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  setState(() {
    _imageURL = dowurl.toString();
  });
  showAlertDialog(context);
  print(_imageURL);
 }
```

This is my code for the uploading of image to firebase storage.
How can I make use of the circular progress bar to indicate to the user that the image is still uploading.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: Can i somehow add the isloading inside my upload image function becos my build function has a lot of stuff going on

Comment: The widget condition has to be inside the build function but the variable isLoading can be inside the uploadImage function as in the answer

Comment: ok thanks but now the circular progress indicator is taking the whole black page. How can i make it occupy the same page ?

Comment: You can use a column widget and add the widget condition inside the column, it depends on what you are doing.. You can add it in a row or column for example

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean instance variable `isLoading` and update it accordingly. Example:

```
bool isLoading = false;


Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    isLoading = true; //add this line
  });
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('event_profile/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
  var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  setState(() {
    _imageURL = dowurl.toString();
    isLoading = false;
  });
  showAlertDialog(context);
  print(_imageURL);
 }
```

And then inside the `build` method, you can have the following:

```
            isLoading
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : Visibility(visible: false, child: Text("test")),
```

So, this way when `isLoading` is equal to false then the `CircularProgressIndicator()` will not appear, when it changes to `true` `setState()` will call the `build()` method and `CircularProgressIndicator()` will appear.